# How to define events and properties in a decorator

Tags: c#, design-patterns, decorator

I defined an interface which has an event and a property defined as follows.

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    event EventHandler SomeEvent;
    string GetName();
    string IpAddress { get; set; }
}
```

I then created a class and using it, every thing works fine.

Now I want to extend this class using a decorator. **I am not sure how to handle the event. For the property I think I am clear, just want confirmation**.

I defined the decorator class as follows.

```
public class LoggerDecorator : IMyInterface
{
    private readonly IMyInterface _MyInterface;
    private readonly ILog _MyLog;
    public LoggerDecorator(IMyInterface myInterface, ILog myLog)
    {
        if (myInterface == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("IMyInterface is null");
        _MyInterface = myInterface;

        if (myLog == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("ILog instance is null");
        _MyLog = myLog;

    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        // If needed I can use log here
        _MyLog.Info("GetName method is called.");
        return _MyInterface.GetName();
    }

    // Is this the way to set properties?
    public string IpAddress
    {
        get
        {
            return _MyInterface.IpAddress;
        }

        set
        {
            // If needed I can use log here
            _MyLog.Info("IpAddress is set.");
            _MyInterface.IpAddress = value;
        }
    }


    // But How to handle this evetn?? Please help. I am not clear about this.
    public event EventHandler SomeEvent;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't handle the event, you could raise the event:

Like:

```
if(SomeEvent != null)
    SomeEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

of in C# 6.0

```
SomeEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Comment: Ok, I think I am getting it. Let me try.

Comment: When defining an event. Other object could register to it. So your object can do a 'callback' without 'knowing'/restricting to the receivers class. This way you can reuse classes that can notify/call methods.

Answer (score 10):

You can forward the subscription and unsubscription of the event to the element being decorated using `add` and `remove`. That way, if you subscribe to `LoggerDecorator.SomeEvent`, you actually subscribe to the inner `IMyInterface.SomeEvent`.

In your case, it should look like this:

```cs
public class LoggerDecorator : IMyInterface
{
    (...)

    public event EventHandler SomeEvent
    {
        add => _MyInterface.SomeEvent += value;
        remove => _MyInterface.SomeEvent -= value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I got the answer.

The following goes in the ctor.

```
        _MyInterface.SomeEvent += _MyInterface_SomeEvent;
```

and the event handler method will be as follows.

```
    private void _MyInterface_SomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var someEvent = SomeEvent;
        if (someEvent != null)
        {
            someEvent(this, e);
        }
    }
```

The full implementation would be as follows.

```
public class LoggerDecorator : IMyInterface
{
    private readonly IMyInterface _MyInterface;
    private readonly ILog _MyLog;
    public LoggerDecorator(IMyInterface myInterface, ILog myLog)
    {
        if (myInterface == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("IMyInterface is null");
        _MyInterface = myInterface;

        if (myLog == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("ILog instance is null");
        _MyLog = myLog;

        // This is change 1.
        _MyInterface.SomeEvent += _MyInterface_SomeEvent;
    }

    // This is change 2
    private void _MyInterface_SomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var someEvent = SomeEvent;
        if (someEvent != null)
        {
            someEvent(this, e);
        }
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        // If needed I can use log here
        _MyLog.Info("GetName method is called.");
        return _MyInterface.GetName();
    }

    // Is this the way to set properties?
    public string IpAddress
    {
        get
        {
            return _MyInterface.IpAddress;
        }

        set
        {
            // If needed I can use log here
            _MyLog.Info("IpAddress is set.");
            _MyInterface.IpAddress = value;
        }
    }


    public event EventHandler SomeEvent;

}
```